# React router V6.5 : how to strongly type data loaders?

Tags: typescript, react-router-dom, dataloader

using React-Router V6 and I tried to strongly type the dataloader functions that are using `params` and also the `useLoaderData` hook.

So far I have to do the following that is ugly :

A- For `useLoaderData`, need to force the returnType :

```
const profil = useLoaderData() as TProfil;
```

I guess it would be cleaner to create a generic hook like `export declare function useLoaderData<T>(): T;` instead of export `declare function useLoaderData(): unknown;`

B- for the dataloader, what is the type of the params received ? Had to force to `any`, but this is uggly. How to strongly type this and declare somewhere that params is made of "id" which comes from the parameter name in the Route definition ?

```
const careerDetailDataLoader = async ({ params }: any): Promise<TProfil> => {
  const { id } = params;
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/careers/${id}`);

  const data: TProfil = await res.json();
  return data;
};

<Route path=":id" element={<CareerDetailsPage />} loader={careerDetailDataLoader} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First question

> I guess it would be cleaner to create a generic hook like export declare function useLoaderData(): T; instead of export declare function useLoaderData(): unknown;

**Any solution using generics only hides a necessary type cast using `as` so the generic version gives a false sense of type safety.**

[Remix](https://remix.run/) has exactly the generic `useLoaderData<T>()` that you suggest.
At the [remix github repo](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/blob/40a4d7d5e25eb5edc9a622278ab111d881c7c155/decisions/0003-infer-types-for-useloaderdata-and-useactiondata-from-loader-and-action-via-generics.md), there is a detailed explanation of why they deprecated the generic version of the function and why the `useLoaderData()` function which they ported to react-router v6 does not use generics.
(The suggested helper function in the other answer has the same problem as the deprecated function in remix.)

### Second question

> for the dataloader, what is the type of the params received ?

In `react-router`, there is `ActionFunctionArgs` which leads to `Params` being defined (in `@remix-run/router/dist/utils.d.ts/Params`) like this:

```js
export type Params<Key extends string = string> = {
    readonly [key in Key]: string | undefined;
};
```

However, you might want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/76579584/5882233 for a similar question (and potentially a cleaner solution) about the argument types of the `loader` and `action` functions of `react-router` v6.

Answer (score 15):

I encountered the same problems as you when I first used *deferred* loaders last night.

I came up with the following helper functions as a workaround for the lack of type safety when using `react-router-dom`:

```
// utils.ts
import { Await as RrdAwait, defer, LoaderFunctionArgs, useLoaderData as useRrdLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";

export function useLoaderData<TLoader extends ReturnType<typeof deferredLoader>>() {
    return useRrdLoaderData() as ReturnType<TLoader>["data"];
}

export function deferredLoader<TData extends Record<string, unknown>>(dataFunc: (args: LoaderFunctionArgs) => TData) {
    return (args: LoaderFunctionArgs) =>
        defer(dataFunc(args)) as Omit<ReturnType<typeof defer>, "data"> & { data: TData };
}

export interface AwaitResolveRenderFunction<T> {
    (data: Awaited<T>): React.ReactElement;
}

export interface AwaitProps<T> {
    children: React.ReactNode | AwaitResolveRenderFunction<T>;
    errorElement?: React.ReactNode;
    resolve: Promise<T>;
}

export function Await<T>(props: AwaitProps<T>): JSX.Element {
    return RrdAwait(props);
}
```

Usage:

```
// MainLayout.tsx
import { Await, deferredLoader, useLoaderData } from "./utils";

export const mainLayoutLoader = deferredLoader(args => ({
    metrics: api.metrics.get()
}));

export const MainLayout: FC = () => {
    const data = useLoaderData<typeof mainLayoutLoader>();

    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<SiderMenu />}>
            <Await resolve={data.metrics}>
                {metrics => <SiderMenu metrics={metrics} />}
            </Await>
        </Suspense>
    );
};
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <MainLayout />,
        loader: mainLayoutLoader
    }]);
```

Where:

- `api.metrics.get()` returns a type of `Promise<Metric[]>`
- `useLoaderData<typeof mainLayoutLoader>()` returns a type of `{ metrics: Promise<Metric[]>; }`
- `metrics` inside `{metrics => ...}` inside the `<Await>` node will be typed as `Metric[]`
- `args` are of type `LoaderFunctionArgs` as defined in `react-router-dom`, which results a type of `{ [key: string]: string | undefined; }` for `args.params`