# Parameter types in React Router action method

Tags: typescript, react-router

I'm trying the [React Router tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial#updating-contacts-with-formdata) in TypeScript. The code works but I find it hard to identify the parameters' type definitions, e.g.

```
export async function action({ request, params }) {
    const formData = await request.formData();
    const updates = Object.fromEntries(formData);
...
```

From debugging I can see the variable `request` is a type of `Request`, however I can't find such a type when trying to import.

A similar question regarding the `params` parameter.

Can someone help a confused .NET C# dev here, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Aside from `action`, none of these APIs we're discussing are provided by React Router: `request`, `request.formData`, `Object.fromEntries` are all provided by the web platform.

`Request` is an interface of the Fetch API, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request

It is defined in the `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts` file.

[params](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader#params):

> Route params are parsed from [dynamic segments](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#dynamic-segments) and passed to your loader

`params` TS type should be defined by the user. We can get it using the [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) hook.

So the complete TS version of `action` should be:

```
type MyParams = {
  contactId: string;
}
async function action({ request, params }: { request: Request; params: MyParams; }) {}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Freshman to this typescript world.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ActionFunction` from `react-router`. That way, the types of the arguments are inferred correctly:

```js
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import type { ActionFunction } from "react-router";

export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request, params }) => {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const updates = Object.fromEntries(formData);
  await updateContact(params.contactId, updates);
  return redirect(`/contacts/${params.contactId}`);
}
```

If you want to type the arguments directly instead of the function you could use `ActionFunctionArgs` from `react-router` but I don't see an advantage of doing that.

(Using the type `LoaderFunction` for the `loader` method works exactly the same.)

Answer (score 1):

https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-meets-react-router in the case of integrating react-query as the new react router stands, it seems that `ActionFunctionArgs` may be necessary if you want the nicety of type inference via `intialData`